# Separately appending all the elements of a list to all the elements of another list in python

Tags: python, list

Im working with two lists, both with nested elements inside them, and Id like to create one final list that combines all the nested elements. Like the two lists are,

```
A=[[["a1", "b1"]],[["a2", "b2"]]]
B=[[["a3", "b3"]],[["a4", "b4"]]]
```

and Im need to find a way to separately append all the elements from list B into the elements of list A.
The output would be something like this,

```
C=[[["a1", "b1"], ["a3", "b3"]],[["a1", "b1"], ["a4", "b4"]], [["a2", "b2"], ["a3", "b3"]],[["a2", "b2"], ["a4", "b4"]]]
```

This is the way Ive been trying to work it out but its not giving the correct output.

```
C=[]
for i in A:
    i[1].append([i[0] for i in B])
    C.append(i)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
A = [[["a1", "b1"]], [["a2", "b2"]]]
B = [[["a3", "b3"]], [["a4", "b4"]]]

C = []
for ai in A:
    for bi in B:
        C.append(ai + bi)
```

Or the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) version:

```
A=[[["a1", "b1"]],[["a2", "b2"]]]
B=[[["a3", "b3"]],[["a4", "b4"]]]

C = [ai + bi for ai in A for bi in B]
print(C)
```

**Output**

```
 [[['a1', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3']], [['a1', 'b1'], ['a4', 'b4']], [['a2', 'b2'], ['a3', 'b3']], [['a2', 'b2'], ['a4', 'b4']]]
```

As an alternative use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

A=[[["a1", "b1"]],[["a2", "b2"]]]
B=[[["a3", "b3"]],[["a4", "b4"]]]

C = [ai + bi for ai, bi in product(A, B)]
print(C)
```

Comment: `[a + b for a in A for b in B]` you could just do this, no need for `product` and the extra import, although they are equivalent.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
for i, j in A, B:
    C.append(i + j)
```